# forever fails startup when using -l param

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm using [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) to keep the Ghost blogging platform and few other services running independent of a console session. I run this command from within a *nodejs* script using the 'child_process' module like so:

```
var shell = require('child_process').spawn;
var params = [
    'NODE_ENV=production',
    'forever', 
    '--sourceDir', rootDir + '/scripts', 
    '--pidFile', logDirectory + '/service.pid',
    'start', 
    '-l', "chimp.forever.log",
    '-e', logDirectory + "/error.log",
    '-o', logDirectory + "/info.log",
    'chimpStart.js'         
];
var forever = shell('sudo', params);
```

This seems like it should work but it only works once. On the second attempt the existence of the forever log file (specified in the `-l` parameter) means forever refuses to start.

BTW, I have validated that this is what causes the problem by removing the `-l forever.log` parameters. With this configuration it has no problem with the other log files being statically named (or the PID of the service).

Is there anyway of avoiding this other than removing the forever log file manually prior to trying to restart?

Comment: I just now noticed that if I set the `--uid` parameter to something static that I get the same behaviour. In both cases the "exit" event returns an error code of 255.

Comment: Try adding `-a` or `--append`, as specified in the [documentation](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line). I don't think the default behaviour is to append.

Comment: @BenFortune I wasn't sure I actually wanted to append log files but it probably is a good outcome and it definitely seems to solve the problem. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ah. In that case have you checked the permissions?

Comment: Well I thought it would be covered that this being run by 'sudo' so permissions should be covered, right?